# Using DeleteAllOnSubmit when the table has no primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to delete records from a DB which has no primary key. The following works:

```
using (myDataContext db = new myDataContext ())
{
    db.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE TradeDate = {0}", date);
}
```

(where `date` is an input to the function). But when I try convert it to LINQ

```
using (myDataContext db = new myDataContext ())
{
    db.myTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(db.myTable.Where(t => t.TradeDate.Date == date.Date));
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I get the following error because the table doesn't have a primary key:

> Additional information: Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(myTable)' because it has no primary key.

I found the following old posts about this issue

[DB:4.44:Dml Operations Using Linq Query For A Table Without Primary Key zm](http://www.hivmr.com/db/a733739ac119cjf81j9kdxd8afjfa9s9)

[Dml Operations using linq query for a table without primary key.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48bca7f0-2c86-4c0b-a8b4-258ac344fbfb/dml-operations-using-linq-query-for-a-table-without-primary-key?forum=linqprojectgeneral)

But I don't understand how to implement the fix they suggest (i.e. setting another key to `IsPrimary`).

Is there a way to do this using LINQ? Bear in mind that adding a PK to the actual SQL table is not an option (unless I just add a row counting identity column).

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: @RahulTripathi added the error wording

Comment: If you dont want to set primary key on table in database, try setting primary key through Linq to SQL designer.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN How do I do that?Also, I haven't been using the sql designer but I can set a primary key on my table object, however will it not be a problem that the table object has a primary key but the actual SQL table does not?

Comment: You can easily set IsPrimaryKey=true to your object. It will then just fool the linq that your table is having primary key.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN and are there any side effects to doing that that I need to consider?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN  I tried that and now I get the error `Sequence contains more than one element`

Comment: @Dan... You can use `SingleOrDefault()` method to return null (or default value, `0` for int) if there are no records.

Comment: You can refer [Setting IsPrimaryKey=true on column in table with no primary key]( http://www.dskims.com/setting-isprimarykey-true-on-column-in-table-with-no-primary-key/) for side effects of using `IsPrimaryKey=true`.  And the error clearly says that there must be two or more records which fulfills your where condition,

Comment: @MicrosoftDN There are 4 records that match the where condition when I get this error. To me, the error sounds like it's complaining because there are multiple matches. Unless I'm misunderstanding what the error means by *sequence*?

Comment: @Dan...If you are expecting multiple elements but just first one *Replace* the `Where` with `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @user2946329 I'm not following, I am expecting multiple elements and want to delete them all in one go, not just the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a primary key the two interfaces aren’t emitted: `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and so LINQ to SQL doesn’t know that your record has changed. Do the following:

1. Open the LINQ Designer.
2. Open the properties window for the table you want to delete a record from.
3. Click on any of the columns in the entity you want to delete and you'll see a property labeled "Primary Key".
4. Change the value to true for column you want to use as a primary key.

Comment: There is no suitable column to use as a primary key though... so can I just pick the `TradeDate` column? Also I'm not using the LINQ designer (couldn't find tutorials!) and define primary keys for my tables like this `[Column(Storage = "_Ticker", IsPrimaryKey = true)]` (as an example). I'm assuming that's the same thing though?

Comment: @Dan...As I said your table should have a primary key. So the solution is simple: **define a primary key in your table**. It would be better you consider adding one more column to your table as primary key or maybe use `TradeDate ` column.

Comment: The table can't have a primary key. Adding a primary key to the actual SQL table is not an option. Although unlikely, it is possible for there to be two identical records in this table.

Comment: Then you can't use update or delete through EF with that table.

Comment: @Dan...How about adding one identity column to consider as rows??

Comment: @user2946329 is that a wise idea though? Would that be recommended over just using ` db.ExecuteCommand`?

Comment: @Dan...You need one primary key anyway. I think defining one auto increment column shouldn't have any problem for you and also it helps you to be able do update and delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Please, use the unique column as a Primary Key in the EF model.**

Otherwise use **DataContext.ExecuteCommand()**

Comment: If you want to delete using DeleteAllOnSubmit() then you must have primary key column in your table. so you can add one identity column to consider as rows.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed, you need to add a primary key to your table. And then execute the query.

Else you can try to delete the row manually like this:

```
var query = myTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<Date>("TradeDate") == date.Date);

foreach(var row in query.ToList())
   row.Delete();
```